# I want the view to remain static but the content to re-orient within the view

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, resize

I am making a view with several subviews for iPad. I want all the positioning and sizing of the subviews to stay the same when rotating the iPad, but the content inside the subviews to re-orient. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you still need to layout the views depending on the orientation. However, you're portrait and landscape frames would have different proportions on the screen.

An Example of how you might layout a view:

```
int h = 300;
int w = 100;
int space = 50;

CGRect frame;
if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ) {

   frame = CGRectMake( space, space, w, h );
}
else if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) {
    frame = CGRectMake( self.view.bounds.size.width - w - space, self.view.bounds.size.height- h - space, w, h );
}
else if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) {
    frame = CGRectMake( space, self.view.bounds.size.height- w - space, h , w );
}
else if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
    frame = CGRectMake( self.view.bounds.size.width - h - space, space, h, w );
}

self.label.frame = frame;
```

Comment: thelaws, thanks, this works. I found it easier to just use the autoresize, either way the screen shifts and I think users are more used to the resize motion than a total redo of the screen.